# In MVC, how do I receive messages that occurred between page loading and SignalR client connection?

Tags: signalr

I want to notify clients about changes to a state on the server.

When a request for a page is received, I return a snapshot of the current state to the client. Between the time when the snapshot has been taken and the client has created the connection to a hub, the state may have been changed and notifications are sent to the hub.

How can I send all the events that happened between the time of the snapshot and the client connected to the hub?